# CSS file updates don't apply in ASP .NET CORE

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a CSS file for my homepage, it's just a simple transparent background image.
When I change something in that file, it does not apply the changes, older version is compiled.
Even if delete that file completely from computer, it still loads it (I saw that within inspect element).

My view has just link to that CSS file and nothing else. It has defined Layout page also.

It's happening to me all the time. If I create some other as source, it works but I get the same problem for that new file also after the initial version.

What could itbe ? I'm fairly new in ASP .NET CORE but it looks like it's storing those files in a server. One time I accidentally opened console in inspect element and got some bad connection error and it worked from that point on.

Comment: It's probably just your browser caching the CSS files.

Comment: Try hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) your browser

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your browser is caching your css file. A common way to force it to use the updated version is to add the attribute `asp-append-version="true"` to all your link and script tags so that your browser always fetches the most up to date version.